# How do I take a string and remove parts from it to convert to doubles

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, double

Sorry for the bad title. I really don't know how to title what I want to do very well.
Anyways, I'm building a calculator on Cocoa in Objective-C with X-Code. I already have all the buttons mapped out, etc. I need to make the math part of the calculator work.
Now, my original idea is to have each button print a NSMutableString to the calculator "monitor" (textfield) and then convert to doubles. This is all in working order, and I wish to keep it. HOWEVER, the part that is not working, is my idea of how to go about doing math on the numbers.
I can convert to doubles just fine:

```
[display1 appendString:@" - "]; // Appends to the monitor
[self updateDispaly:display1]; // Yes, updateDisplay is a custom-built method.
math1 = display1.doubleValue; // Converts the NSMutableString to doubles.
```

Thats all good.
Now, I'm having this all happen in each operation button's code (Subtract, add, etc) and want it to happen in the EQUALS button's code. How would I separate both sides of the " - ", and then convert to doubles after this is done?

```
[display1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
```

That's an idea of some code I had, but this wouldn't work for all the symbols, and what happens to those components?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: lots and lots of ways to do what you want, if you are starting with a string, you could look at NSScanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library [on github called DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) by a respected SO member, [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong).  He points out correctly that infix expression parsing is kind of a black hole, and it's better to find a competent library, which is what he provides.

In a nutshell, grab the repo from github, copy the DDMathParser folder into your project and #import "DDMathParser.h".  It looks like the library does much more, but it will certainly do a simple calculator as follows:

```
// this is an infix expression from your user input, like: @"-1 + 3.14"
NSString *expression = self.display1.text;

// thanks to DDDMathParser, just do this:
NSNumber *answer = [expression numberByEvaluatingString];
NSLog(@"%@", answer);
```

Comment: This answer is mainly working, except for the `self.display.text;` part. What do you mean there? Do you mean replace that with my string, in this case display1, or the textfield object, in my case `answerField`?

Comment: it's the string that contains the expression to parse.  you're getting it from a text field?

Comment: Yeah, okay, got that working. Last thing I'm going to ask before I stop bugging you on this, it's not displaying the @"-" when I log the array. How do I make sure that it's there?

Comment: your followup question made me realize that my answer was badly flawed, parsing out the operators which is part of what you need.  I modified the answer with new advice.  Sorry for the head-fake.  I downloaded and tried the library and it works to the extent I claim in my answer (and probably much more).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NSScanner`. Or you could use `componentsSeparatedByString:`. Or you could cut the whole process short and use `NSExpression`.

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"4 + 5"];
id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

Comment: `NSScanner` would work a treat in this situation given the string mixes words and numbers

Comment: When did he mention using words?  `NSExpression` is likely better